# Is there a keyboard shortcut to lock my Mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini

I have tried Command + Control + Q, but that doesn't work. Is there another one, or is there a way to set up my own custom keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Did you check the  menu shows Cmd/Ctrl/Q as the shortcut & that no other app is using the same one?

Comment: Yeah no other app is using it

Comment: & does it work if you just select it manually from the menu?

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch **System Preferences** and go to the **Keyboard** pane.
2. Next, select the “**Keyboard Shortcuts**” tab. From the list on the left, select “**Application Shortcuts**”. Click on the plus (+) button below to add your new shortcut.
3. In the dialog box, we’ll want to leave “All Applications” selected in the first menu. Enter “Lock Screen” as the Menu Title. Finally, enter your keyboard shortcut. Let’s go with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
4. Click Add and you’re all done!

[image]

You also can explore https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 for the official Apple shortcut.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Did you try the different key combinations with Shift, Command and other keywords? Also when you put Command + Control + Q in Keyboard Shortcut did you get any red error showing conflict?